# Existential statement containing "at least $2$"

Tags: logic

How do I disprove something like

> There are at least two real numbers $x$ satisfying $x-1=1-\frac{1}{x}$?

Is showing that $x-1=1-\frac{1}{x}$ has only one real root enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The negation of the statement you are trying to disprove is "there are less than two real numbers x satisfying this equation". If you prove that there is only one real number x satisfying that equation, then you have proven the negation, and so the original statement is false.